# SQL error with count and displaying name

Tags: sql, database

I am looking to write a stament that gets all booked towns and counts them

So the town name is displayed alongside the number of times it appears in the table.

```
SELECT COUNT(town) AS Town_Bookings 
FROM booking b, customer c
WHERE b.cid = c.cid;
```

Currently this just displays the number of towns that are in the table, whereas I wanted it to count each town and display the name

I tried

```
SELECT town, COUNT(town) AS Town_Bookings 
FROM booking b, customer c
WHERE b.cid = c.cid;
```

however this result in the error

```
Query failed: ERROR: column "c.town" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include columns in `GROUP BY` Clause if they are not part of aggregate function.

Also I would specify it as join.

```
SELECT town
       ,COUNT(*) AS Town_Bookings
    FROM booking b
    INNER JOIN customer c
        ON b.cid = c.cid
    GROUP BY town
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a group by clause, like the error message tells you :

```
SELECT town, COUNT(town) AS Town_Bookings 
FROM booking b, customer c
WHERE b.cid = c.cid
GROUP BY town;
```

Also write your join explicitly. Often it makes no difference, but by writing it clearly, you have full control and don't let the query optimiser guess what join you intended.

```
SELECT town, COUNT(town) AS Town_Bookings 
FROM booking b inner join customer c on b.cid = c.cid
Group by town;
```

Comment: Group By needs to come after the WHERE

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I missed that

Answer (score 0):

write it as follow:-

```
SELECT town, COUNT(town) AS Town_Bookings 
FROM booking b, customer c
WHERE b.cid = c.cid;
group by town
```

when you use any `aggregate function` you must use `group by` with it.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the group by clause. The query should be:

```
SELECT town
       ,COUNT(town) AS town_bookings
    FROM booking b
       ,customer c
    WHERE b.cid = c.cid
    GROUP BY town
```